# Validation failed (numeric string is expected)

Tags: javascript, typescript, swagger, nestjs

I have a problem with controller in `nestJS` framework, can someone tell me what is wrong below? After launch this controller i have `Bad request`, I don;t have idea what is wrong, i have simillary endpoint where this work properly but here is not work ;/

```
    @Delete('/remove/:projectId')
    @AuthRequired()
    async removeProjectGlobally(@CurrentUser() user: User, @Param('projectId', new ParseIntPipe()) projectId: number): Promise<ResponseHandler> {
        return await this.projectService.removeProject(projectId, user);
    }
```

```
Error: Bad Request

Response body
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Validation failed (numeric string is expected)",
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: The request you're trying to send would be helpful, can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that the `projectId` parameter is expected to a numeric string like `"123456"` and it apparently is some other string with non numeric characters.

That is enforced by the `ParseIntPipe()` part of where the parameter is declared, which will decode `"123"` into `123` or throw an error if it cannot do that because it is not a number.

```
@Param('projectId', new ParseIntPipe()) projectId: number
```

It's hard to advise more with more info about your request, if you are sending a request with a path like `/remove/123456` then it should behave as you expect.